What is the maximum contribution allowed to my HSA if my husband is enrolled in a PPO plan, while both my child and I are enrolled in a CDHP/HSA plan?
What is the maximum contribution allowed to my Health Savings Account (HSA) if my husband is enrolled in a PPO plan, while both my child and I are enrolled in a CDHP/HSA plan?

To determine what your HSA contribution limits are, we first need to determine if you are an eligible individual.  You are generally an eligible individual if you are enrolled in an HSA-compatible health plan (usually called HDHP, but sometimes called CDHP) and are not personally covered by another non-HSA compatible health plan.  The details are in Publication 969, but the important thing here is that your husband's health coverage does not prevent you from being an HSA eligible individual.  However, if your husband's health plan does cover you, then it does prevent you from being an HSA-eligible individual.  So if you want to contribute to an HSA, you need to make sure that your husband's health plan does not cover you.
Next, we need to determine whether you are considered to have self-only coverage or family coverage.  IRS Publication 969 has this to say about self-only and family coverage:

Self-only HDHP coverage is HDHP coverage for only an eligible individual. Family HDHP coverage is HDHP coverage for an eligible individual and at least one other individual (whether or not that individual is an eligible individual).
Example. You, an eligible individual, and your dependent child are covered under an “employee plus one” HDHP offered by your employer. This is family HDHP coverage.

Your HDHP plan covers you and your child.  That means that if you yourself meet all the requirements for being an HSA-eligible individual, then you are considered to have family HDHP coverage and can contribute at the family limits.  If you are HSA-eligible every month in 2024, your 2024 contribution limit is $8300.

For HSA contribution purposes there are two plan types: self-only and family. The inclusion of anyone on your plan in addition to yourself (spouse, dependent, domestic partner, etc.) changes your plan and corresponding contributions from "self-only" to "family".
Therefore, you can contribute the family maximum of $8,300 in 2024 since you and your child are enrolled in an HSA-eligible high-deductible health plan.
The family max of $8,300 may be limited if you don't have family HDHP coverage at the start of the month of every month during the calendar year (e.g. if you had self-only coverage and added your child later in the year, or if you switched to the HDHP mid-year). However, if you satisfy the "last-month rule" (essentially needing to maintain HDHP coverage from December 1 of this year through December 31 of the following year), you can still make the full $8,300 contribution. See IRS Pub 969 for information on contribution limits and the last-month rule.
Additionally, even if you husband went on his own HDHP and became HSA-eligible separately from you and your child, the family limit of $8,300 still applies to the whole family (not $8,300 for your family plan and $4,150 for your husband's).
